# Is there is a function that helps to predict missing values using k-NN in R?

Tags: r, class, knn

I have a dataset DF1 that has 10 missing values and I want to use k_NN to approximate those missing values. Firstly, I create two datasets DF2(without missing values) and DF3 (with only missing values). I used `class` package. The code is `knn_res <- knn(train.X, test.X, train.Y, k = 4)`. as a result, I tried to use `predict()` function to predict those missing values from the DF3, but had not any results. What function should I use to solve my problem and predict those missing values?

the following codes I used:

```
    data("iris")
    iris<-iris
    iris[1:10,1]<-NA
    normalization <-function(x) { (x -min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
    library(fastDummies)

    Dataset<-dummy_cols(iris)
    Dataset<-Dataset[-5]

    Dataset_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(Dataset[,c(2:7)], normalization))
    Dataset_norm<-cbind(Dataset[1],Dataset_norm)

    DF2<-na.omit(Dataset_norm)
    DF3<-Dataset_norm[1:10,]


    ran <- sample(1:nrow(DF2), 0.7 * nrow(DF2)) 

    train <- DF2[ran, ]
    test <- DF2[-ran, ]

    #  Select the feature variables
    train.X=train[,c(-1)]
    # Set the target for training
    train.Y=train[,1]
    # Do the same for test set
    test.X=test[,c(-1)]
    test.Y=test[,1]


    library(class)

    error_normal <- c()
    set.seed(12)
    for(i in 1:25){
    # Perform a KNN regression fit
    knn_res <- knn(train.X, test.X, train.Y, k = i)
    # Compute R sqaured
    error_normal[i] <- sqrt(sum((test.Y - as.numeric(knn_res))^2))
    }
    min(error_normal) #choose k=17
    knn_res <- knn(train.X, test.X, train.Y, k = 17)
```

Comment: Is train the same as DF2?  Is test the same as DF3?

Comment: I modified the question, so there is a real example

Answer (score 0):

Try the caret knn package as shown in this working example.

```
# Create sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
    X1 = round(runif(100, 1, 100)/100,2), 
    X2 = round(runif(100, 1, 100)/100,2),
    X3 = round(runif(100, 1, 100)/100,2), 
    X4 = round(runif(100, 1, 100)/100,2),
    X5 = round(runif(100, 1, 3),0)
)
df$X5 <- ifelse(df$X5 == 1, 'setosa', ifelse(df$X5 == 2, 'versicolor', 'virginica')) # Add category

# Remove some data (for later imputation)
df[1:20,'X4']<-NA

# Build the model to predict for the missing X4 data
train_data <- subset(df, !is.na(X4)) # Create train set
library(caret)
knn_fit <- train(
    X4 ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X5, 
    data = train_data, method = "knn", 
    trControl = trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 3), 
    preProcess = c("center","scale")
    )
knn_fit # View model results (optional)

# Append the predicted X4 values to the original dataframe
df$p_X4 <- predict(knn_fit, df)
# Overwrite missing X4 values with predicted X4 values
df$X4 <- ifelse(is.na(df$X4), df$p_X4, df$X4)
```